# Como quebrar linha dentro de dicionários em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
socios = {}    
def cadastro():
         addSocio = input("Digite o nome do sócio que deseja cadastrar: ")
         telefoneSocio = int(input("Digite o número de telefone do sócio (DDD + NÚMERO): "))
         cpfSocio = input("Digite o CPF do socio: ")
         socios[addSocio] = ("|telefone: {}| |CPF: {}|".format(telefoneSocio,cpfSocio))
         print("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!")
```

sou iniciante em python e estou tentando criar uma cadastro de sócios utilizando dicionários conforme o código acima, queria saber como quebrar linha após o cpf de cada sócio, para que quando eu utilize o print os dados sejam impressos na tela de forma organizada.

Comment: Acho que a quebra de linha em Python é com `\n`, experimente algo assim: `"telefone: {}\nCPF: {}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O formato que está sendo gravado como objeto `python`, se o objetivo somente for exibir na tela de forma mais organizada, podemos converter em `json` e assim exibir:

```
import json
#seu código
print(json.dumps(socios, indent=4))
```

Resultado:

```
{
    "Marcelo": "|telefone: 44999451668| |CPF: 07786794884|",
    "Juarez": "|telefone: 44995585585| |CPF: 48857785958|"
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, é exatamente isso que eu estava querendo.